# XSD - unique values of two different attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

It is possible at schema level to enforce unique values of two attributes with different name?

```
<xs:complexType name="exampleType">
  <xs:attribute name="first" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute name="second" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

If `first` is 1, `second` needs to be some other value.

EDIT: I am using xsd 1.0.

Comment: Which version of XML Schema are you using? If you're using 1.1 you could just add an `<xs:assert test="@first != @second"/>` child to the complex type.

Comment: If `first` and `second` were elements instead of attributes you could do what you want using `unique`, but I don't know how you can do that with attributes.

Comment: please post your answer with elements instead of attributes, but the name of elements need to stay different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment this is only valid if `first` and `second` are elements (not attributes). The `|` xpath operator it's like a union of nodes.

```
<xs:element name="exampleElement" type="exampleType">
    <xs:unique name="firstAndSecondDifferent">
        <xs:selector xpath="first | second" />
        <xs:field xpath="." />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="exampleType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="first" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:element name="second" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

The following element is valid (`first` and `second` have different values):

```
<exampleElement>
    <first>1</first>
    <second>5</second>
</exampleElement>
```

The following element is valid (no `second` element present):

```
<exampleElement>
    <first>1</first>
</exampleElement>
```

The following element is not valid (`first` and `second` have the same value):

```
<exampleElement>
    <first>1</first>
    <second>1</second>
</exampleElement>
```

This can't be done with attributes because `selector xpath` doesn't allow to use attributes so `"@first | @second"` it's not a valid value of the xpath attribute of a selector.

Comment: thanks, i didnt know about xpath | operator, i will try to redesign it using elements